# Why does Sublime Text snippet work only at the last row?

Tags: xml, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimetext-snippet

I'm trying to create my own snippet for Sublime Text 3. Here it is:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
// begin $1
.$1$2
// end $1
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>di</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.pug, text.pug</scope>
</snippet>
```

but it works only at the last row of document. what's wrong?

[image]

Comment: Seems to work find here. What package are you using to provide the Pug syntax that you're using?

Comment: @OdatNurd I'm using https://github.com/davidrios/pug-tmbundle

Comment: My best suggestion would be to ask you if, when this is happening, you happen to have used some other snippet just before? Or put another way, when it doesn't work does the status line in the window say anything about `Field X of Y`?

Comment: @OdatNurd no I don't use any other snippet, just open .pug file, click at the line between existing lines, Enter, write "di", Tab and nothing happens. Status bar doesn't show anything too